# Moving the meta link to the same spot it occupies on MO.

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface

Is there any chance we could move the link to meta to the right of the FAQ link?  Arguments are forthcoming.

Comment: I like the idea. idk if it's possible before the beta is over.

Answer (score 2):

The current location is standard for StackExchange 2.0 sites. See [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), or [pro webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). 
 Personally, I always look for it at the bottom, because that's where it is on StackOverflow. Having it in two places would be my recommendation, since neither spot is obtrusive.